# Delete a shape which name starts with a certain string

Tags: excel, vba

How can I delete a shape which starts with a certain string?

No need for a loop(?) There is only one "MyButton", but with different number after "MyButton".

```
worksheets("sheet1").Shapes("MyButton" & "*").Delete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop to check the names.

```
Dim shp As Shape

For Each shp In Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes
    If shp.Name Like "MyButton*" Then
        shp.Delete
    End If
Next shp
```